# Webthread locking main thread when app is entering foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiwebview, youtube-api

I'm using UIWebView to embed YouTube HTML player in my iOS app, sometimes when app is entering foreground from background (and the video is playing), the app just frozen, I got 0x000000008badf00d crash.

```
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.myapp.myapp failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 6.460 (user 6.460, system 0.000), 27% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 3.069, 13% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39911f9c __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3997b298 _pthread_mutex_lock_contended + 48
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39977d36 _pthread_mutex_lock + 258
3   WebCore                         0x36e2f190 _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 40
4   WebCore                         0x36e2ffb8 WebThreadLock + 76
5   WebCore                         0x36e6b962 -[TileLayer layoutSublayers] + 14
6   QuartzCore                      0x3106db3a CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 346
7   QuartzCore                      0x3106d9cc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
8   QuartzCore                      0x3106d3e0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
9   QuartzCore                      0x3106d1f2 CA::Transaction::commit() + 310
10  AVFoundation                    0x2da4fb60 -[AVPlayerLayer _updateSubtitles:forceRender:] + 696
11  AVFoundation                    0x2da500a8 -[AVPlayerLayer layerDidBecomeVisible:] + 200
12  QuartzCore                      0x3106bbf4 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 80
13  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
14  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
15  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
16  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
17  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
18  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
19  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
20  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
21  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
22  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
23  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
24  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
25  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
26  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
27  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
28  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
29  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
30  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
31  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
32  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
33  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
34  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
35  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
36  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
37  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
38  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
39  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
40  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
41  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
42  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
43  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
44  QuartzCore                      0x3106bc30 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 140
45  QuartzCore                      0x3106cb82 CA::Layer::set_visible(unsigned int) + 346
46  QuartzCore                      0x3106c9e6 CA::Context::set_layer(void const*) + 134
47  UIKit                           0x313feab2 -[UIWindow _createContext] + 1138
48  UIKit                           0x316572a4 _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder + 172
49  UIKit                           0x31657158 +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsPassingTestForAppResume:] +         12
50  UIKit                           0x315fc534 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 72
51  UIKit                           0x313fb60e -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1878
52  UIKit                           0x313fadf4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
53  UIKit                           0x3145f400 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612
54  GraphicsServices                0x33a68b52 _PurpleEventCallback + 606
55  GraphicsServices                0x33a6873a PurpleEventCallback + 30
56  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb91844     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
57  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb917de __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
58  CoreFoundation                  0x2eb8ffaa __CFRunLoopRun + 1402
59  CoreFoundation                  0x2eafa764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
60  CoreFoundation                  0x2eafa546 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
61  GraphicsServices                0x33a676ce GSEventRunModal + 134
62  UIKit                           0x3145988c UIApplicationMain + 1132
63  myapp                           0x0003ba0e main (main.m:14)
64  myapp                           0x0003b9c4 start + 36
```

Basically I use a `UIWebView` to load an HTML file with YouTube HTML player, and use `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsString]` to control it (like `loadVideoById()`, `play()`, `pause()` etc.). There is also some mechanism so the app can plays video in background, most of the times it works well, this crash only occurred after it plays several videos in background, and trying to enter foreground, but hard to reproduce.

Seems like webthread is locking main thread so iOS kill my app, I've researching this problem for several weeks but with no luck, any suggestions are all welcomed.

Comment: can you add the html? Any thread you run on native?

Comment: Please provide more code - and for events generating too.

Comment: I successfully embedded youtube videos in an iOS app using their [iOS player helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper). You will find more documentation in [Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper). If you use this, be careful that you can't have more than one instance playing at the same time IN THE APP. So make sure to force stop/pause playback in viewDidDissapear or other similar methods, in case you want to have a player in several view controllers

Comment: @MariusConstantinescu: I already embed youTube HTML player in my app successfully, and it works most of the times, this crash is hard to reproduce. I'm pretty sure their is only UIWebView instance will embed HTML player in my app, thanks for your suggestion =)

Comment: @trick14: I didn't specifically dispatch in any thread, but I use javascript to control my YouTube HTML player, should I call [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString] in main thread or any thread?

Comment: @SergeyNikitin: I just updated my question below the crash report, thank you.

Comment: @CarlosChen a little late here, but make sure you're calling any methods that directly involve the player (play, pause, stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString) on the main thread.  I've had crashes like this occur because I was calling methods like these off of the main thread.

Comment: @JAL Thanks. I use [_webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:jsString waitUntilDone:NO]; in my code now =)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of experiments, this issue can be avoided by hiding html player div tag with CSS when app goes into background, then show it again **AFTER** received **appDidBecomeActive** event.

I think YouTube html player is trying to do something UI related when app becomes active, so it might lock main thread and get 0x000000008badf00d crash.

Hope this answer can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue on iOS 7 only when trying to call `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` with an HTML string containing the YouTube iFrame player on a background thread.  Moving that call to to the main thread with all of my other UI calls seemed to fix the issue.

I should note that I wasn't able to recreate this issue with iOS 8 and 9, so it's possible this was also a WebKit bug that was fixed with a later iOS update.